# Create Data Cube in SQL

Tags: sql, olap, cube, olap-cube

Given the tables and descriptions below, I'm trying to use SQL with GROUP BY, CUBE and ROLLUP to create a cube. There's something wrong with my query because the base is supposed to return ~1440 rows, but the base of my cube only returns 59...

```
Tb_Supplier(Supp_ID, Name, City, State)
Tb_Consumer(Con_ID, Name, City, State)
Tb_Product(Prod_ID, Name, Product_Category, Product_Line, Product_Packaging)
Tb_Offers(Supp_ID, Prod_ID, Quantity, Price)
Tb_Requests(Con_ID, Prod_ID, Quantity, Price)
Tb_Transactions(Tran_ID, Supp_ID, Con_ID, Prod_ID, Quantity, Price)

The dimensions of the cube are: Tb_Supplier and Tb_Product.
Measure groups table is: Tb_Offers.
Measure aggregates: SUM(Quantity), SUM(Quantity*Price), 
MAX(Price) , MIN(Price).
Dimension hierarchies:

Tb_Supplier:    State > City > Name
Tb_Product:     Product_Packaging  > Name 
            Product_Category > Product_Line > Name


SELECT DISTINCT S.Name "Supplier Name", S.State "Supplier State", S.City "Supplier City",
P.Name "Product Name", P.Product_Packaging "Product Packaging",
P.Product_Category "Product Category", P.Product_Line "Product Line",
SUM(Quantity) "Total Transactions Quantity", SUM(Quantity*Price) "Total Transaction Price",
MAX(Price) "Maximum Price", MIN(Price) "Minimum Price"
INTO Tb_Offers_Cube
FROM Tb_Supplier S, Tb_Product P, Tb_Offers O
WHERE S.Supp_ID = O.Supp_ID 
AND O.Prod_ID = P.Prod_ID
GROUP BY CUBE((S.State, S.City, S.Name),
(P.Product_Packaging, P.Name),
(P.Product_Category, P.Product_Line, P.Name)),
ROLLUP(S.State, S.City, S.Name),
ROLLUP(P.Product_Packaging, P.Name),
ROLLUP(P.Product_Category, p.Product_Line, P.Name);
```

Comment: Have you tried to use left join?

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ I have not. Would I be creating a join on the dimension tables then? I'm fairly new to cubes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to create cross tabular report. Use `INNER JOIN.. USING..` statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.Name "Supplier Name"
    , S.State "Supplier State"
    , S.City "Supplier City"
    , P.Name "Product Name"
    , P.Product_Packaging "Product Packaging"
    , P.Product_Category "Product Category"
    , P.Product_Line "Product Line"
    , SUM(Quantity) "Total Transactions Quantity"
    , SUM(Quantity*Price) "Total Transaction Price"
    , MAX(Price) "Maximum Price"
    , MIN(Price) "Minimum Price"
INTO Tb_Offers_Cube
FROM Tb_Supplier S 
INNER JOIN Tb_Product P USING(P.Supp_ID)
INNER JOIN Tb_Offers O USING(O.Prod_ID)
GROUP BY CUBE((S.State, S.City, S.Name),
    (P.Product_Packaging, P.Name),
    (P.Product_Category, P.Product_Line, P.Name)),
ROLLUP(S.State, S.City, S.Name),
ROLLUP(P.Product_Packaging, P.Name),
ROLLUP(P.Product_Category, p.Product_Line, P.Name);
```